# Download/update dependent framework into ios project automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, git, jenkins

I am using a framework/library for my iOS project. That framework is also created by me and uploaded as private on GitHub.
I want to update the added framework into my application project on the basis of version number automatically whenever I pull from git or build my app.

How can I achieve this for ios app? Can it be done through Jenkins or through git or xcode or some other approach is there?

I have no idea how it could be done. Please help and share ideas. Thanks!

Comment: as per your requirement I think `CocoaPod` is best to fetch your latest framework from GIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your looking for a dependency manager. There are two available. The Ruby based [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org) and native OS X [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage). Of the two, I think Carthage is the easiest to learn because it does not change your project's settings and only needs a simple file to setup.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response! I was implementing Carthage and have a query i.e My framework has multiple targets. After building particular target, i used the particular created xxx.framework bundle into my application project.How can i build for specific target and use that xxx.framework within aap's project using Carthage?

Comment: Carthage will automatically build all Shared targets. So if you have a target for an iOS framework and a target for a tvOS framework. Make sure that the schemes for both are set to Shared. You can limit which targets are built using the --platform argument. ie. '--platform iOS' will only build iOS frameworks.